How can I use Jackson's @JsonAnySetter with a record class?
I'm trying to use Jackson's feature to deserialize unknown fields into a map, using @JsonAnySetter. This works fine for a Java class with the field annotated with @JsonAnySetter, but does not work with records:
public class SerdeTest {
    private static final String CONTENT = "{ \"name\": \"foo\", \"bar\": \"baz\" }";

    private ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    static class ThisWorks {
        public String name;
        @JsonAnySetter Map<String, String> others;
    }

    @Test
    public void deserClass() throws IOException {
        var data = om.readValue(CONTENT, ThisWorks.class);

        assertThat(data.name, equalTo("foo"));
        assertThat(data.others.get("bar"), equalTo("baz"));
    }

    record ThisDoesnt(String name, @JsonAnySetter Map<String, String> others) {}

    @Test
    public void deserRecord() throws IOException {
        var data = om.readValue(CONTENT, ThisDoesnt.class);

        assertThat(data.name, equalTo("foo"));
        assertThat(data.others.get("bar"), equalTo("baz"));
    }
}

How can I use this annotation with a record?

This might help you https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3439#issuecomment-2075469872

Short Answer
Records are not yet supported with @JsonAnySetter as cleanly as you would expect - referencing this GitHub issue.
Long Answer
IMHO, the concept of making use of a record type contradicts to the flexibility that you are seeking along with @JsonAnySetter Map<String, String> others. While with one you are declaring an immutable type with reduced boilerplate code, on the other hand in practice you are seeking to update the attributes of the entity without adhering to a fixed construct.
As an alternate from the linked thread, what you could attempt is to override a custom constructor and accessors for the others attribute such as follows to make it work:
record ThisDoes(String name, @JsonAnySetter Map<String, String> others) {

    @JsonCreator
    ThisDoes(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this(name, new HashMap<>());
    }

    public Map<String, String> others() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(others);
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    private void updateProperty(String name, String value) {
        others.put(name, value);
    }
}

(verified with v-2.15.3)
But do note, this also takes away the reduction of boilerplate code that one might seek as a benefit during the migration towards record representation.
